# Can't SSH, but can TeamViewer

Tags: ssh, firewall, port, teamviewer

I would like to SSH into a computer behind a firewall that blocks SSH connections (incoming and outgoing).  Amusingly, I can still access the computer using the remote-desktop software TeamViewer.  I assumed that TeamViewer is allowed in because it uses a different port than SSH's default port 22, so I added the following ports to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Port 22
Port 443
Port 80
Port 5938
Port 10000
```

and then tried to connect to each of them in turn using (e.g.)

```
ssh user@remote-computer.com -p 5938
```

None of the ports work: I still get a `Connection timed out` error.

Why can TeamViewer connect to the remote computer while SSH can't?  How can I SSH into (or out of) the remote computer?

Comment: There is nothing amusing about it.  It's just how stateful firewalls work.  You're connecting to it via another host which has an active connection to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to connect via SSH to a computer behind the firewall, then you will need to add a port forward (DNAT) rule to the firewall mapping port 22 (or whatever port you decide to use) to the SSH port on the internal server.

TeamViewer is able to get through by using techniques such as [NAT Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) and [UDP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) to establish a connection through the router to the PC.  While TeamViewer connections are peer-to-peer (client connects directly to host) the initial connection is established with the help of TeamViewer's servers which tells the host that a client is trying to connect and then helps facilitate the NAT traversal by having the server and client try to open connections which will then put the firewall in a state where it will allow the TeamViewer connection to pass through to the host.

Traffic for the TeamViewer connection to the host computer passes through the router much like the traffic from visiting a webpage would when the browser on the PC goes through the firewall to request a webpage and then have the response delivered back to it.  The main difference is that "tricks" are used to open the appropriate ports on the client firewall/router and allow the connection through from the remote TeamViewer client.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is by using reverse port forwarding in ssh:

On the server do:

ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 _internet_server_you_own

So you will end up with ssh to your machine on port 2222 on the internet_server. I think it was covered on serverfault before.